# How to eliminate Nulls, and insert with split delimter

Tags: t-sql, split, null

```
drop table #temp

Create Table #Temp 
( 
col1 Varchar(20), 
col2 Varchar(20), 
Col3 Varchar(50), 
col4 Varchar(20)
)

Select * From #Temp 

Insert Into #Temp(col1)
Select * From SplitDelimiterString('123,456', ',')

Insert Into #Temp(col2)
Select * From SplitDelimiterString('abc,def', ',')

Insert Into #Temp(Col3)
Select * From SplitDelimiterString('fff,ggg', ',')

Insert Into #Temp(col4)
Select * From SplitDelimiterString('520002,520003', ',')

Select * From #Temp
```

FYI, SplitDelimiterString is a function. 
-- Code for SplitDelimiterString

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitDelimiterString] (@StringWithDelimiter VARCHAR(8000), @Delimiter VARCHAR(8))

RETURNS @ItemTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(8000))

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StartingPosition INT;
    DECLARE @ItemInString VARCHAR(8000);

    SELECT @StartingPosition = 1;
    --Return if string is null or empty
    IF LEN(@StringWithDelimiter) = 0 OR @StringWithDelimiter IS NULL RETURN; 

    WHILE @StartingPosition > 0
    BEGIN
        --Get starting index of delimiter .. If string
        --doesn't contain any delimiter than it will returl 0 
        SET @StartingPosition = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@StringWithDelimiter); 

        --Get item from string        
        IF @StartingPosition > 0                
            SET @ItemInString = SUBSTRING(@StringWithDelimiter,0,@StartingPosition)
        ELSE
            SET @ItemInString = @StringWithDelimiter;
        --If item isn't empty than add to return table    
        IF( LEN(@ItemInString) > 0)
            INSERT INTO @ItemTable(Item) VALUES (@ItemInString);            

        --Remove inserted item from string
        SET @StringWithDelimiter = SUBSTRING(@StringWithDelimiter,@StartingPosition + 
                     LEN(@Delimiter),LEN(@StringWithDelimiter) - @StartingPosition)

        --Break loop if string is empty
        IF LEN(@StringWithDelimiter) = 0 BREAK;
    END

    RETURN
END
```

-- The result set is

```
Col1    Col2      Col3    Col4

123     NULL      NULL    NULL
456     NULL      NULL    NULL
NULL    abc       NULL    NULL
NULL    def       NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL      fff     NULL
NULL    NULL      ggg     NULL
NULL    NULL      NULL    520002
NULL    NULL      NULL    520003
```

--  I need a result set like
-- The result set is

```
col1      col2      col3      col4

123       abc       fff       520002
456       def       ggg       520003
```

Please help.

Comment: The problem is not well defined. What is the association of different columns in that requirement?

Comment: You need to define how these are related. Is it simply position in the delimited string? If so, you could also return the row number from the function and then join these together to make 1 insert statement.

Comment: @user3605493, glad I was able to point you in the right direction. You should post your solution as the answer and accept it instead of just editing it into the post. It is OK to answer your own questions on this site.

Comment: @liebs19 How can i do that? I am new to this website.

Comment: @user3605493 Take the text you edited into you post and put it in the "Your Answer" text box at the bottom and then click the "Post Your Answer" button. Once the answer is posted you should be able to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--- Figured out my self. Thanks to @liebs19 for logic

```
BEGIN TRAN

Create Table #Temp1

( 

RowID int not null identity(1,1) primary key,

col1 Varchar(20), 

)

Create Table #Temp2 

( 

RowID int not null identity(1,1) primary key,

col2 Varchar(20), 

)

Create Table #Temp3 

( 

RowID int not null identity(1,1) primary key,

col3 Varchar(20), 

)

Create Table #Temp4 

( 

RowID int not null identity(1,1) primary key,

col4 Varchar(20), 

)

Insert Into #Temp1(col1)

Select * From SplitDelimiterString('123,456', ',')


Insert Into #Temp2(col2)

Select * From SplitDelimiterString('abc,def', ',')

Insert Into #Temp3(Col3)

Select * From SplitDelimiterString('fff,ggg', ',')

Insert Into #Temp4(col4)

Select * From SplitDelimiterString('520002,520003', ',')


Select  #Temp1.Col1, #Temp2.col2, #Temp3.Col3, #Temp4.Col4 

From #Temp1 

Inner Join #Temp2 ON #Temp1.RowID = #Temp2.RowID

Inner Join #Temp3 ON #Temp1.RowID = #Temp3.RowID

Inner Join #Temp4 ON #Temp1.RowID = #Temp4.RowID 


ROLLBACK TRAN
```

-- This is the output finally I am looking for.

```
col1      col2      col3      col4

123       abc       fff       520002
456       def       ggg       520003
```

.